# How to plot raster layers in R with no legend?

Tags: r, plot, raster, r-raster

I am trying to plot a raster layer with no legend or scale bar on the side. I do not want to use ggplot and want to only work with base R or raster packages. This is because I also want to overlay additional raster layers over the initial one with no legend, and this appears hard to do in ggplot.

Here is the raster layer I am using and want to be plotted without a legend/scale bar:

```
library(raster)
library(RColorBrewer)

# Define common variables
extent.x <- 100
extent.y <- 100
resol    <- 100

# Half-forest terrain layer
env <- raster(nrow=extent.x,ncol=extent.y,xmn=0,xmx=(extent.x*resol),ymn=0,ymx=(extent.y*resol),resolution=resol)
env[1:50 ,] <- 1 # Plains
env[51:100 ,] <- 2 # Forest
plot(env)

# An example layer that I would like to plot over the env layer
popLayer <- env
popLayer[,] <- 0
popLayer[50,50] <- 1000

# Define a new color gradient for the pop raster layer
rasterColors <- colorRampPalette(c("white", "red"))

# Set breaks of the gradient
cuts <- c(0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000)

# Plot the env layer, then plot the pop layer on top of it and use the color gradient above
plot(env)
popLayer[popLayer == 0] <- NA
plot(popLayer, add = TRUE, col = rasterColors(2))
```

As you can see, the two scale bars are also plotted over each other and are unreadable. How can I plot the first layer with no legend so the second layer's scale is legible?

I have tried looking at using par() to manipulate the legend plotting, but I am not sure how to apply it to my situation where I am plotting two raster layers over each other. As mentioned, I also tried using ggplot but this also proved difficult to apply.

This is my first question so thank you in advance and apologies if some formatting is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `legend = FALSE` inside the first `plot` call

```r
plot(env, legend = FALSE)
popLayer[popLayer == 0] <- NA
plot(popLayer, add = TRUE, col = rasterColors(2))
```

[image]